# Html table with multiple rows

Tags: html, css, grid

I want to expand a column and display a set of rows inside it.

What I am trying to achieve :

[image: Original output]

What I have achieved so far

[image: My try]

My code:

```
<table style="background-color:lightgreen"  border="1">
 <tr >
     <td>Id</td>
     <td>Name</td>
     <td>Col1</td>
     <td>Col2</td>
     <td>Group Related Column (value for each expanded cell)</td>
     <td>Col4</td>
 </tr>
 <tr >
     <td  rowspan="5" >#1</td> 
     <td  rowspan="5">AFSBEESS1</td>
     <td rowspan="5">
         <tr><td>[-] Group Name</td></tr>
         <tr><td>#1 in Group</td></tr>
         <tr><td>#2 in Group</td></tr>
         <tr><td>#3 in Group</td></tr>
     </td>
    <td rowspan="5">
         <tr><td>[-] Group Name</td></tr>
         <tr><td>#1 in Group</td></tr>
         <tr><td>#2 in Group</td></tr>
         <tr><td>#3 in Group</td></tr>
     </td>

     <td>x</td>
     <td>x</td>
 </tr>
```

​

My fiddle input : http://jsfiddle.net/yDUZg/78/

What is the best table format to do the same?

Is there some plugins to achieve the same effect of easily grouping the column?

Or a better approach to the problem?

Doing in ASP.NET, but as this is a basic thing , I am tagging it as HTML

Comment: show your css please. My guess is that you have a rule that applies to all rows globally which is affecting the layout of your sub rows.

Comment: You have a nice picture of what you have already – but I can't imagine what are you trying to do? As of your description you already have your solution…

Comment: @feeela that is done using Excel :)

Comment: @Rohith Nair Ah, OK – then you should write that in your question. Not: This is what I have, but "this is want I'd like to achieve". BTW: You are trying to display a relation between tables inside a single table. "Group Name" should be a column header instead of some cell content. Your table just confuses me. Isn't there any better solution to display that information?

Comment: feeela what I am trying to achieve is the best way.GroupName is just a generic name I gave. Consider this group as say Developers and when I expand it shows C# developer HTML programmer , and next row will have a different group naming:: say Drivers and when you expand it, it will have two wheel driver, four wheel driver etc. Hope you got what I am trying to achieve..

Comment: @ryan its plain HTML no CSS is applied

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at something like - http://www.jankoatwarpspeed.com/post/2009/07/20/Expand-table-rows-with-jQuery-jExpand-plugin.aspx ?

This plugin allows you to collapse/expand table rows as required.

You html above is wrong, as you nesting `tr` within `td` elements.  When you add `rowspan="x"` to a column, you should omit it for the next `x` rows. eg,

```
<table>
<tr>
   <td rowspan="2">Funky</td>
   <td>Joy</td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td>Fun</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

You are getting confused over the concept of rowspan - http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/tables/index_famsupp_30.html

For now, I have created a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xrnBK/) that does what you have requested.  The example is highly specialised, and may not work in a generalised way.  In the fiddle, I have removed the `rowspan` and `colspan` properties.  Feel free to add them in when you are comfortable with what they do.

Comment: I tried to do the same in my fiddle, but unable to get the same result :(. Can you show me an example with the same result in between two columns. The examples I see work when there is just two columns and no extra columns to disturb the layout

Comment: excellent.. I arrived at similar solution. But because of problems with my HTML markup, toggling is not working :( . Thanks I will refer your markup and correct mine :) .

Comment: I use jquery toggle to expand and hide. Can you help me with this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/yXCVb/42/

Comment: You do not have a filter in place that will return on the required results - the rows that need to hide / show.  You need to expand your selectors to allow or this, but your html is complex and difficult to read.

Comment: I was testing the toggle option with a generic code.. Its either a table markup issue or because of toggling, my rowspan is causing problems (when items being hidden). I will figure that out. Thanks for your help

Comment: Do you have any specific reason , to use simple row/column concept? I was looking at a row group concept , because I am iterating over a dataset and building the markup. List->Inner List->Inner Inner List.

Comment: I removed the `rowspan` and `colspan` to facilitate the example.  Having read over the html again, you can check if the row is a child or not, as a parent will separate child groups.  So, I have your example working to some degree - http://jsfiddle.net/N3zEA/.  But there is still an error in your html - you are missing a `tr` or something.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20575/discussion-between-kami-and-rohith-nair)

Answer (score 0):

If you're set on using tables then why not just nest them? Where you want the rows to appear within a cell, just add another table.

Comment: Hi if i set it inside a table, will i get the same position as column 2 and column 3? Won't I be pushing column 2 and column 3 to the right?

Comment: for this type of data display it is perfectly valid to use a table, even the preferred method.

Comment: Yes sorry you will, and of course tables are valid when displaying tabular data. It appears I answered this a little too quickly so apologies for any wasted time

Answer (score 0):

You can probably do this with JavaScript. I think it would look something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
...
// You could use these in an event (inside some callback function)

$('tr.expand').style.visibility = 'hidden'
$('tr.expand').style.visibility = 'visible'

// OR you could use these...

$('tr.expand').show();
$('tr.expand').hide();
...
</script>

<!-- And then of course the group of <tr>'s you want to expand 
     on an event would all have the same class -->

<table>
...
<tr class="expand">
    <td>...</td>
</tr>
<tr class="expand">
    <td>...</td>
</tr>
...
</table>
```

Comment: hi thanks for the method to expand and collapse. but sadly i am currently stuck at a good way to represent these multiple rows in a cell